# $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(-1)^{\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2} }}{n} $, solving this limit using Stolz theorem and getting the wrong result

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(-1)^{\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2} }}{n} $$

It is easy to see that this is zero since the demoinator goes to infinity and the numerator oscillates between -1 and 1.But if i try to solve it differently by using the fact that
$$ 1+2+3+...+n=\frac {n(n+1)} {2} $$ so we can express $$\frac {(n-2)(n-1)} {2} = 1+2+3+...+n-2$$ 
Now we have a limit 
  $$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(-1)^{1+2+3+...+n-2}}{n} $$ 
We can solve this with Stolz cause n is monotonous and unbounded. And we get $$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(-1)^{1+2+3+...+n-1}-(-1)^{1+2+3+...+n-2}}{n+1-n} =  \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(-1)^{1+2+3+...+n-1}-(-1)^{1+2+3+...+n-2}}{1} $$ The first and second term in the numerator have different signs ( because the exponents differ by $1$ 
) So we have $$ -1 -1=-2 , or ,1-(-1)=2$$ **My result is that this limit doesnt exist where is my mistake**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theorem states

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=L\implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=L$$

that is “if the LHS limit is $L$ then the RHS limit in $L$“, but if the RHS limit is $L$ we can’t conclude that also the LHS limit is $L$.

Comment: I didnt know that, thanks

Comment: Just refer to the statement of the theorem! You are welcome! Bye